# Clap on Clap Off Switch

Tags: transistors, 555, electret

[image: Example of Clap Switch Circuit]

I would like to ask why the switching component of this circuit (Q1 with the condenser electret mic) works? From what I understand, the mic has to be supplied a voltage for it to operate.  Hence, there is a DC voltage across it whether it receives a sound or not.  When it is connected that way, wouldn't it always turn Q1 on - thereby triggering a high on the 555 - regardless of the mic detecting a sound? However, I saw the demonstration video and it works as it should - clap on and clap off to toggle the LED D1 (of course having a time in between the claps).

Here's a link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVAMNR_zIQE

Note: The circuit and the video aren't mine.  It is from circuit digest.

Comment: Depends if point A is above or below 1/3rd supply voltage. Not a good design.

Comment: Well considering that there is a DC voltage across the mic regardless of picking up a sound, then the voltage at A would be below 1/3 Vcc always right? But the video was able to show it functioning as intended, which implies that the mic does indeed turn Q1 on and off.  How is that possible?

Comment: They may simply have been lucky that the transistor had a particularly low gain and it just happened to work - as I say not a good design.

Comment: Oh okay, so I have two questions. 1) What is the connection of having a low gain that made them lucky for Q1 to turn on and off? 2) How should the switching section of this circuit be designed if a mic and a switching transistor were to be used?

Comment: (1) A low gain transistor would require more base current to pull its collector low. This current is highly dependant on the value of R4 (47k) - so perhaps just a 'lucky' combination. (2) That would essentially be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: What did you mean by "pull its collector low?"

Comment: With no current through a transistor (no base current) there is no current through the collector load (resistor) so there is no voltage drop - the collector voltage would be at the supply voltage. When you put a small current into the base of the transistor the transistor amplifies this (by its current gain) and a current flows through the collector resistor - dropping (or pulling down) that collector voltage to something below the supply voltage. The more base current, the lower the collector voltage until it reaches the saturation point (about 0.1 - 0.4V) i.e. fully turned on.

Comment: This circuit is incomplete. (1) You should not DC-couple the microphone output to the transistor Q1. We only need a AC signal. The components' normal variations in characteristics will lead to wide product-to-product performance. Use a low-power opamp (e.g. TL061) as a high-gain AC preamp/schmitt-trigger.  (2) The trigger input to the 555 should be AC-coupled. Put an RC differentiator here.

Comment: (3) A 555 draws to much standby-current for a battery power. Use a CMOS version, e.g. TLC555. (4) The 74S74 is the wrong version for a 9-volt battery. You need the CMOS version, 74C74 or 4013. (5) The 74C74 should not drive an LED directly. The output current very limited, like 3mA.  Add a NPN transistor stage, for current gain.

Answer (score 2):

The author of the article says this: -

> Condenser Mic basically converts sound energy into electrical energy

And this is not true - it's true for a moving coil or moving armature microphone but electrets/condensors require power to produce the electrical energy.

If R4 is made high enough in value then it's possible that the JFET in the microphone (I'm assuming that the microphone is an electret type and not a true condenser despite what the author says) is starved of current and is basically unresponsive to sound below a certain threshold. Notice how the guy "hits" the microphone to trigger it. This, in normal operation would produce a signal of many tens of milli volts and will be enough (as demonstrated in the video) to turn on the transistor Q1 briefly. A different microphone might not work at all in my opinion so I conclude that the circuit is flaky.

On the other hand many different types of microphones might work with possible changes to the value of R4 - I've never seen any information in a microphone's data sheet that can tell you the starvation point of an electret so it's guesswork.

Because good EEs tend to want to see hard claims about this or that in a data sheet, not having the information means uncertainty and unreliability creeps in - it may work first time but fail to work as it warms up or cools down. It might need R4 adjusting for a different (but the same part number) of microphone. If you made ten then some might be really sensitive whilst others don't work.

Comment: My conclusions exactly +1

Comment: So essentially, the current through the JFET affects the operation of the mic? that's why he had to tap the mic just to get a response such that it will turn Q1 on? Even so, doesn't the DC voltage across the mic, with or without picking up a sound, turn Q1 on?

Comment: There will be a lower but constant dc voltage across the Mic. This needs to be present to partially bias Q1 because the bare signal from the Mic won't be enough to fully turn on the transistor without some help from the DC bias.

Comment: Because data sheets don't inform us about the residual dc voltage on the Mic when starved of current we cannot predict whether Q1 is off, partially conducting (optimal for this circuit) or fully on. That is why it is a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit has a little bit of a happy accident.  Your description is correct.  Because the trigger is always low, the output will always be high.  But the discharge will always be off too.  This means between claps, the capacitor will have charged and the 555 is just waiting for that positive pulse on the trigger to momentarily turn the output off.  So when you clap the trigger goes high, the discharge turns on, and output goes low as it has been waiting to do.  The edge toggles the flop and the output goes high waiting for the whole thing to repeat.  Beside the strange way the 555 is being run, the 7474 doesn't like 9V either.  You should find a better circuit.